# How to enable Print button in PrintPreview using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using below code in`Workbook_Open()`event:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrintPreview).Show
```

at very first time when I click on enable content then preview page is opened but Print option is disabled

[image]

Comment: Does something like `Sheets.PrintPreview(True)` enable your buttons?  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-printpreview-method-excel)

Comment: You should clarify that you want to print on file opening and add your Office version including bitness on newer (>2010) versions.

Comment: I used Sheets.PrintPreview(True) also. But as I mentioned print option is disabled very first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same strange behavior on Excel 2007.

Workaround: use [Application.OnTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:00"), "PrintPreviewOnWorkbookOpen"

End Sub
```

And the Sub`PrintPreviewOnWorkbookOpen` in a module

```
Public Sub PrintPreviewOnWorkbookOpen()

  ThisWorkbook.PrintPreview

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using the Legacy version of print preview.

Similar question was asked on the [official Microsoft forums here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/49c85222-0c29-4223-9040-1ae68cfcee57/quotrows-to-repeat-at-topquot-in-page-setupsheet-disabled-in-excel-2010?forum=excel)

The best reply quoted here:

> Hi
>
> **By deault the option for settiing print area, rows to repeat and
>   columns to repeat are greyed out if you display the Page Setup dialog
>   via the Print option.** "I go to print and go to Page Setup".
>
> **I would suggest using the Print Titles button on the Page Layout tab
>   in the ribbon to make the neessary changes.**
>
> As you are a veteran of previous versions this greying out was the
>   case if you activated Page Setup from the Print Preview options but
>   not through File, Page Setup.  In the shuffling of the user interface
>   from 2007 onwards,  **File, Print is effectively the equivalent of the
>   old Print Preview and the Page Setup options in the Page Layout tab
>   the equivalent of the "old" File Page Setup.**
>
> Hope this helps

So to sum it up

I'd probably recommend the following code instead:
Obviously may need some tweaking depending on your desired functionality. It's not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve.

```
Private Sub to_pagelayout()
   ActiveWidow.View = xlPageLayoutView
End Sub
```

Produces the following result

[image]

As for switching actual ribbon tabs, I think that is best reserved for a separate question. I'll also leave the link to the official documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/iribbonui-members-office)

Comment: I am using Excel2016 version. I have some vba code written in Workbook_Open() function.Before End sub I am using Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrintPreview).Show.

Comment: @KunalGupta yes you are, but you are trying to open legacy printpreview options that were uptodate in Excel 2007 and discontinued in further versions (similar issue as Legacy Sharing vs Sharing in excel compatibility)

Comment: then any alter solution for this printpreview

Comment: There isn't one (or not that I am aware of one). This is probably the closest you can get to it.

Comment: Can you please share me the link where it mentioned printpreview option is only upto Excel2007 and it is not working for excel2016

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively use

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
```

which is the same as pressing File › Print.

---

Since it seems that this odd behavior only occurs when macros were disabled before:

Define ["trusted locations"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4) or [digitally sign](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01) your VBA code with a trusted certificate to solve this issue. Digitally signed code or code in trusted locations is executed without any message (with the accordingly set properties in the Trust Center).

It's anyway a good idea to sign your own/company code to get rid of these messages for trusted code and make people sensitive to that message again (so that it is not clicked away carelessly).

Comment: You recognized that he uses the`Workbook_Open()`event to print on startup and this causes the problem?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Well, ⓐ I cannot reproduce the issue the OP has with the `Workbook_Open()` event (it is not grayed out for me). ⓑ I'm using also Excel 2016 as the OP does (see 1st comment below Rawrplus's answer). And ⓒ I suggested this as alternative because the PeviewAndPrint dialog is a different dialog and might not have this issue at the OP's setup.

Comment: You have set Macro-Security -> Disabled with message? If macros are allowed everything is fine. Error raises only after enabling macros on Workbook Startup in the message that pops up..

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Ah, well then this is the perfect solution because defining ["trusted locations"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4) or [digitally signing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01) the  VBA code with a trusted certificate will solve this issue (without any odd workaround). It's anyway a good idea to sign your own/company code to get rid of these messages for trusted code and make people sensitive to that message again.

Comment: That's true! But not everyone has a trusted cert from a CA and if you open mail attachments without saving first, you shouldn't have a trusted location.And still this behavior is weird for me, what changes if you trust with dialog at startup. Can it be a Ribbon issue?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Well, the cause could simply be a bug, or an odd timing issue. • And you don't need a certificate from a CA you can use a self signed own/company one (I do that) and trust it in Windows or Trust Center. Also I would never open any VBA files from any mail-address without checking the code. If they  are signed by anyone's certificate I trust, they will open trusted from email otherwise not (then I need to check the code and decide if I trust it and copy it to a trusted location). This way you cannot accidentally open untrusted code from email.

Comment: Yes, that's good practice! In my company I have disabled all vba, except ms access, no need for them. But a non CA cert is annoying without an active directory structure (import on every pc, no revoke).Maybe you should add your thoughts to your answer.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Well, for less computers eg. <10 you can import it manually or define trusted locations. If it gets bigger, ok, you need to invest in a server structure (and use GPO) or a CA trusted certificate (not that expensive). But in a company where everyone can run untrusted VBA code from email attachments or in any location of the computer I recommend to order your coffin already. Yes that are costs but its a lot more expensive if you got encrypted by malware. Security first.

Comment: No need to convince me! As I wrote all vba is disabled except a trusted location (hidden from users). for ms access runtime. More important: all users have just minimal privileges.

Comment: Yes I do have privileges to sign in. My Macro setting is Disable all macros with notification. Guys, still this is not resolved my isssue. Please help

Comment: @KunalGupta The easiest way for you might be to add the path of your file to the [Trusted Locations (as described in this link)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4) so the "enable macros" notification disappears.